# How to join the values of two array plus some html code between them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have these two arrays:

```
var numbers = ['one',  'two', 'three'];
var colors  = ['blue', 'red', 'white'];
```

Now I want this output:

```
$('.classname').html("<span id = 'one'>blue</span><span id = 'two'>red</span><span id = 'three'>white</span>");
```

How can I do that?

---

I can use `join` and mix second array with `<span>` but I cannot add `id={arr1-values}`:

```
$('.classname').html('<span>' + colors.join('</span><span>') + '</span>');
```

Comment: If you want to have a connection between the two arrays, better make them an object, or a Map

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but here's the jQuery'ish way -> **https://jsfiddle.net/nf2jpnej/**

Comment: @adeneo Do you know a function like `appendChild()` but not append, I want replace, like `html()` ?

Comment: So why not just use `html()`, it's one of the few jQuery methods that replaces the content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid HTML injection, don't concatenate strings like that. Use DOM methods instead:

```js
var numbers = ['one',  'two', 'three'],
    colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    target = document.querySelector('.classname');
target.innerHTML = ''; // Remove previous contents
numbers.forEach(function(id, i) {
  var el = document.createElement('span');
  el.id = id;
  el.textContent = colors[i];
  target.appendChild(el);
});
```

```css
#one { color: red }
#two { color: green }
#three { color: blue }
```

```html
<div class="classname"></div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how exactly does this *"avoid HTML injection"* ?

Comment: This has a small problem ... My approach in the question uses `.html` but your approach always appends, I don't want that, I want to replace new html with current html ..

Answer (score 1):

Try to build HTML by iterating arrays:

```
var numbers = ['one',  'two', 'three'];
var colors  = ['blue', 'red', 'white'];
var resultHTML = '';
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  resultHTML += '<span id = "'+ numbers[i] + '">' + colors[i] + '</span>'
}

$('.classname').html(resultHTML);
```

Comment: As soon as one of the arrays has a different length, it'll fail

Comment: @mmm the question was quite different

Comment: @mmm In the most of cases the length of arrays are the same, but how to keep it safe if they weren't?

Comment: @mmm the nature of the question implies that the arrays should be the same length

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
var numbers = ['one',  'two', 'three'];
var colors  = ['blue', 'red', 'white'];

$.each(numbers, function(k, number) {
  $('.classname').append("<span id='"+ number +"'>"+ colors[k] +"</span>");
});
```

https://jsbin.com/tobozuliya/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I don't want `.append()`, please write `html()` instead

Comment: simply keep what I have inside append function in a variable with += and outside each, $('.classname').html(the variable that you have inside each);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `colors` and `numbers` are of same length, one liner.

```
numbers.map(function(elm,index){
  return '<span id='+elm+'>'+colors[index]+'</span>'
}).join();
```

As suggested by @mmm it would be better to have in object like

```
{
 number:'one'
 color:'blue'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's better if you could use an object to make the relation between the two arrays e.g:

```
var colors = {one: 'blue', two: 'red', three: 'white'}
```

Then you can loop through the object and append the spans to the element :

```
$.each(colors, function(index,value){
    $('.classname').append("<span id="+index+">"+value+"</span>");
})
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var colors = {one: 'blue', two: 'red', three: 'white'}

$.each(colors, function(index,value){
    $('.classname').append("<span id="+index+">"+value+"</span>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classname"></div>
```

Comment: Objects have no order, though. Since OP uses arrays, I guess order is important.

Comment: @Oriol The OP don't refer to the Order.

Comment: But I used `one`, `two` .. to show the ordering is important for me.. Sorry if I didn't mention it literally ..

Comment: Okay @stack that make since .. you should mention such informations in the OP.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki don't blame OP...it's pretty clear that html output matches array order

Comment: @charlietfl no it's not pretty clear for me the `one, two ...` may refer just to an id ..